# Android Reminder Application

Tags: android

I need to create reminder application based on the date and time from the database (Eg:31-08-2011 10:30,05-09-2011 14:40,etc.. )even if the app is not running.. Database will contain many dates with times. If the time reaches i need to display the notificaiton.How can I do that. Please provide any samples or suggestions

Comment: you can use alarm manager. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: Wrote a tutorial. Notification Reminders: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/notification-for-a-user-chosen-time/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use AlarmManager for this.

```
AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(context, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 
SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), PERIOD, pi);
```

where the PERIOD is your time to something that should be executed in OnAlarmReceiver.
And then, just implement method in

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification();
    notification.tickerText = "10 Minutes past";
    nm.notify(0, notification);
}
```

And also see here,

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Edit: A minor code issue fixed!

Comment: What is onReceive ? is it broadcast receiver ? Can you explain about this ?

Comment: yes, This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving an Intent broadcast. for details check here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent%29

Comment: I know the broadcast receiver but I want to know how we can register broadcast receiver for Alarm manager means How it will call when pending intent fires ?

Comment: In the above code PERIOD can be set as milliseconds or seconds?

Answer (score -1):

Put this code wherever you need..

```
new CountDownTimer(diff, 1) //Constructor for CountDownTimer class (milliseconds,difference);
{
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
{
// DO NOTHING
}

public void onFinish() {
sendSMS(phoneNo,message);
}
}.start();
```

Comment: A bit of explanation, and possible caveats, are definitely in order.